# What affection is required for companion quests?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've hit the far side of the halfway mark in SWTOR, and though I've been lugging Khem Val for most of that (complaining every step of the way), I've yet to be asked to go on any quests for him.

I'm at 2500 / 10000 affection currently.

What affection levels does it take to unlock companion quests? Do you also have to be advanced to a certain part of the main story?

Comment: If you are talking in the form of companion quests as speak to them and answering some questions, then i've mostly noticed that when i finished a planet i would get to talk to him. But if you are talking about quest in the form of like ME2 where you actually have to do something, then i haven't done any.

Comment: @Lyrion There are quests where you have to do stuff and not just talk. Did one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companion quests are locked by affection, character level, and story line.

This can be seen by standing in a cantina and giving the companion gifts until their affection reaches a certain level.  I am unsure what these levels are, but this page has a full list of quests that can be done for Khem Val: http://www.torhead.com/npc/3pcPzNI/khem-val#ends

Comment: After completing act 1, I was able to talk like 10 times with Mako, so there seems to be some connection to the story line.

Comment: There are definite companion quest unlocks tied to storyline progression. They aren't terribly granular though - chapter by chapter it seems.

Comment: That could be true I suppose, mind you I've been following the storyline pretty much exclusively so that was not a factor. I can change the answer to match any new info.

Comment: It's a combination of affection and story line -- you need to be past Class Storyline Event X and have at least Y affection to unlock conversation and/or sidequest Z.

Comment: It is story line. Vette's "I Married a Sith Lord" would hardly make sense if you hadn't become a Sith Lord yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is based on affection and doing 'big'-ish missions. For example, if you're a republic trooper or smuggler, when you do the Esseles flash point when you go to Coruscant, your companion (Aric Jorgan or Corso Riggs). Not just story progression, 'big' missions too - in addition to affection.

I'd recommend getting the affection level up loads, and then just progressing the story and waiting for him/her to want to speak to you.